# Not able to read Model passed by controller on jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-el

I am sending Object with help of ModdelAndView in Spring controller, but i am not able to read it on jsp?

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Tried with EL:

    ${user}

    Try with JSTL:

    <c:out value="${user}"></c:out>

</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class StudentHome {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/Home")
    public ModelAndView RedirectLogin() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/auth/Home");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", "Alex");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

I have tried both Spring EL and jstl its not working. Do i need to include anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to include org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView instead of org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

Answer (score 1):

The model presents a placeholder to hold the information you want to display on the view. It could be a string, which is in your above example, or it could be an object containing bunch of properties.

update your code as follows

```
@Controller
public class StudentHome {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/Home")
    public ModelAndView RedirectLogin() {
        return new ModelAndView("yourJspName","user", "Alex");
    }
}
```

then in your jsp, to display the message, you will do

```
Hello ${user}!
```

hope this will help you..!

Comment: I solved it @Ashish by importing correct package for ModelAndView